# ac compressor pulley making noise

Tags: ac, hyundai, sonata

2006 hyundai sonata 6 cylinder ac compressor pulley is making noise how dangerous is it to drive ? Also is there a temporary fix i could do or is it possible to grease the ac compressor bearing in my car? Thx everyone

Comment: Some more information would help: what kind of noise?  When the car is hot or cold?  Does the sound change at different speeds?

Comment: Including what Bob Cross asked, how do you know it's the A/C compressor pulley (how did you localize it to that location)? Does it make the noise when the A/C is on, off, or both?

Comment: The car makes the noise both hot and cold. It makes it while the AC is on and or when off and car is idling. When driving the sound stops . We changed the belt and lubricated the tensioner and my step father determind it was the compressor pulley . i have a planned vacation next week and i need to know if i can still go (500 mile drive) or if theres a fix i could do. Thanks everyone

Comment: The noise is like a high pitch squeaky sound